# snowflake grant ownership inside stored procedure is ignored

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Anyone else running into this or can replicate?

Expected behavior: clone db and transfer ownership to sysadmin

Observed behavior: clone db but ignore grant ownership statement. No error. No transferring.

```
use role accountadmin;
use database X;
use schema public;
create or replace procedure test_clone_db()
returns varchar
language sql
comment = 'Creates or replaces a Zero-Copy Clone of the X database into Y'
execute as owner
as
declare 
    message varchar;
    time_start timestamp default current_timestamp();
begin

create or replace database Y clone X;
grant usage on database Y to role fake_role;
grant ownership on database Y to role sysadmin;  --why is this being ignored?

message := 'Clone created successfully. Ended at ' || current_timestamp() || ' time elapsed: ' || timestampdiff(seconds, time_start, current_timestamp()) || ' seconds';
return message;
end;
```

Comment: When you look at the Query History what does it show for the "grant ownership..." statement, did it run did it error, etc? Who is currently showing as the owner of the DB - is it the user that ran the SP?

Answer (score 0):

I have executed the code below and it worked as expected.

```
use role accountadmin;
create database x;
-- Start

use role accountadmin;
use database X;
use schema public;

create or replace procedure test_clone_db()
returns varchar
language sql
comment = 'Creates or replaces a Zero-Copy Clone of the X database into Y'
execute as owner
as
declare 
    message varchar;
    time_start timestamp default current_timestamp();
begin

create or replace database Y clone X;
-- grant usage on database Y to role fake_role;
grant ownership on database Y to role sysadmin;  --why is this being ignored?

message := 'Clone created successfully. Ended at ' || current_timestamp() || ' time elapsed: ' || timestampdiff(seconds, time_start, current_timestamp()) || ' seconds';
return message;
end;


use warehouse default_wh;
show databases;
call test_clone_db();

show databases;
```

Here's the screen shot of the output.

[image: Output from the above execution - SHOW DATABASES]